# Django/Python: How to create redirect from one view/url to another?

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, view

Django 1.8 / Python 3.4

I have a website.html that displays entries from my database, each of which is identified by its ID. Now, at the end of each displayed entry I have a link to an "edit" view, looking like this:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'edit' object.id %}">edit</a></td>
```

The link is working fine and leads to the correct view:

```
def edit(request, object_id):
```

implemented in `views.py`. There some code is executed correctly too, and in the view's last line I have:

```
return redirect('website.html')
```

Obviously, after the chosen entry has been edited I want my website.html with the edited entry being displayed in the browser again: `127.0.0.1:8000/website/`. However, what happens is that I get a `Page not found (404)` error, with the information:

```
Requested URL 127.0.0.1:8000/website/2/website.html
```

The "2" here is the ID of the entry.

Maybe I have the wrong idea about how redirects work, but I was assuming that instead of calling the respective view's url from url.py it would open the url provided in the `redirect()` function?!

What happens, though, is that this url gets appended to the view's url!

Here is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from www.list.views import website, edit

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^website/$', website, name="website"),
    url(r'^website/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', edit, name="edit"),
]
```

I'm pretty sure the third url entry is causing the problem but I have absolutely no idea how to change it for the redirect to work. Also, the edit view doesn't have an actual website (template), but I'm supposed to provide a URL for it, so this was the best I could think of.

The way this should work is: Click the "edit" link on website.html, the code from the edit-view is being executed, and, afterwards, the website.html with the change in the database entry gets displayed again.

^^ How to achieve this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake and the solution:

At the end of the edit-view it's correct to write "return redirect('website')". However, just as I assumed, the URL of edit in urls.py was wrong.

Instead of

```
url(r'^website/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', edit, name="edit"),
```

it should just be

```
url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', edit, name="edit"),
```

Thank you nonetheless!

Answer (score 4):

Redirect uses `name`s or absolute URLS. You should either use the *name* of your URL:

```
return redirect('website')   # since name="website"
```

or an absolute URL, like:

```
return redirect('/website/')
```

Comment: I already tried that too, didn't work. I just end up with the same misconstructed url (where the desired url gets appended to the edit view's url) ...

Comment: It works exactly like the template tag `url`. If `{% url 'edit' object.id %}` is producing the correct url using the name `edit`, redirect should work too. Please make sure that the config files you posted are the same as the ones you are actually using.

Comment: I copy-pasted everything, it's definitely the code I'm using. Yes, the link in website.html leads to the edit-view, providing it with the chosen entry's ID. But after the execution of the edit-view's code I wanna get back to my website.html. And that's the part I can't get to work as the website.html URL always gets appended to the edit-view-URL ... (absolute URL didn't work either)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the reverse function instead of redirect

> ```
> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>
> return reverse('website')
> ```

Comment: `reverse` returns the URL for the view, it does not return an `HttpResponse` object.